# Autologin and unlock keyring using LUKS passphrase?

Tags: gnome, pam, luks

I use LUKS full disk encryption on my archlinux system. When i boot my system i used to input the same password three times. That always bothered me.

Recently i found out how to unlock the gnome keyring using the login password.

Now i would really like to reduce the login procedure down to one password entry.

I found [this drawing](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/login-unlock/) which seems to describe exactly, what i want, but could not find out anything about the project status.

Is there a way to achieve my usecase in a similar fashion?